# architectural dilemma - nested Fragments or Activities in tabhost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity

I need to implement such a construction - I have TabHost which contains nested FragmentActivities. I tried to use ActivtityGroup for embedded FragmentActivities, but got an `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@405ceb00 is not valid; is your activity running?`

I'm going to release my application at Gingerbread android version. But I want to implement good version maintaince for application - do not remake whole application for newer versions. But I've built whole application with FragmentActivities. So I've got a dilemma to solve:
1) to save solution with FragmentActivities and make it nested with TabHost;
2) rewrite application and implement Fragments instead of Activities and use only one FragmentActivity;
3) implement ActionBar solution;

I want make it easy with good maintaince. Help please with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later, I refactored my application. ActivityGroup is really bad solution. I use FragmentActivities in Tabs and nested Fragments in it. Everything work fine and more more faster than with ActivityGroups.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use deprecated ActivityGroup and TabActivity for the first version of my application. Then I'd implement Fragments for newer versions.

I used [this](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) tutorial and everything worked fine for me.